# conditional_variable::wait unexpected behavior?

Tags: c++11

I picked up the code from the [conditional_variable::wait reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait). The reference states that :

> wait causes the current thread to block until the condition variable
> is notified or a spurious wakeup occurs, optionally looping until some
> predicate is satisfied.

The link also states that the wait is equivalent to :

> while (!pred()) {
> wait(lock); }

If that is the case, is there a reason why the following code does not work as the original code?

```
#include <condition_variable>
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>

std::condition_variable cv;
std::mutex cv_m; // This mutex is used for three purposes:
                 // 1) to synchronize accesses to i
                 // 2) to synchronize accesses to std::cerr
                 // 3) for the condition variable cv
int i = 0;

void waits()
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(cv_m);
    std::cerr << "Waiting... \n";
    cv.wait(lk, [] {std::cout << "Check Done!" << std::endl; return i == 1; });
    std::cerr << "...finished waiting. i == 1\n";
}

void signals()
{
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(cv_m);
        std::cerr << "Notifying...\n";
    }
    cv.notify_all();

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));

    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(cv_m);
        i = 1;
        std::cerr << "Notifying again...\n";
    }
    //cv.notify_all();
}

int main()
{
    std::thread t1(waits), t2(waits), t3(waits), t4(signals);
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    t3.join();
    t4.join();
}
```

Comment: What are you hoping for? You never `notify_all` after you've set `i = 1` so the only way any of the `waits` threads will ever finish waiting is if they have a spurious wake-up and happen to notice that `i == 1`.

Comment: I was reading the 'Lost Wakup' Section in this https://www.modernescpp.com/index.php/condition-variables blog. The description there lead me to believe that when predicate is true the wait exits automatically.

Comment: Ok, that is a misunderstanding. You need to `notify` or else the waiting thread may never wake up to be able to check if the condition is true.

Comment: So, there is no way to handle as Lost Wakeup scenario? other than settings the predicate and hoping for a spurious wakeup to bless us?

Comment: The lost wakeups (should be _lost notifications_ i.m.o) are already handled in your code. The `wait` checks the condition just before going into waiting mode. I see that the article mentions that too: "_How can this issue be solved? The predicate which got rid of spurious wakeups will also help with lost wakeups. In case the predicate is `true`, the receiver is able to continue its work independently of the notification of the sender._"